# Mac OS X locks up when I plugin in headphones on MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, audio, headphones

Every time I plug in (or off) my headphones (even white iPhone ones), Mac OS X locks up for about 10 seconds, and then works as normal, and even displays the beach ball. Not everything locks up, as I can still switch screens, etc, but I think the Finder does.

Initially I thought this was related to Flash, as the Flash Player would stop working, but this happens even when the browser is closed.

I don't have any audio related apps installed.

Does anybody have any ideas of what could causing this, or tips on how to track down the problem?

Comment: Does anything appear in the All Messages section of Console.app when you do this?

Comment: Do you have any extra audio devices? Like Bluetooth headsets or anything? Could it be trying to access those before falling back to built-in?

Comment: @Spiff: No, I do not use any other audio devices, just the internal sound device.

Comment: @Chealion: I just checked, and no messages appear in the Console.app "All Messages", or in any other logs files there.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why does my computer freeze when I unplug my headphones?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/828/why-does-my-computer-freeze-when-i-unplug-my-headphones)?

Answer (score 2):

Could you try creating a new user and see if it happens there? Create a new user. Restart your computer and log with the new user. Make sure you don’t have anything in the “Login Items” (nothing starts at login).

Also try starting your Mac in “Safe Mode” as described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/1498/115) and see how it goes.

This could be related to a Kernel Extension (ktext) problem.